# При заполнении формы выбивает ошибку, как решить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, chromedriver

При заполнении формы для авторизации на python+selenium выбивает ошибку:
**login_btn.click().send_keys(login).perform()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'**
Из-за чего это может происходить? Xpath менял, по координатам кликал, ничего не работает, что можно сделать?
code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep


def get_url(driver):  # perehodim po ssilkam
    driver.get("https://id.ati.su/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fati.su%2F&iframe=1&fastreg=1")
    print("GOT URL")
    sleep(6)


def authorization(driver):
    login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='ati-id-login']/div[@class='ati-core-popup-content']/div[@class='ati-core-login-wrapper']/input")
    login_btn.click().send_keys(login).perform()
    sleep(2)

    password_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Пароль']")
    password_btn.click().send_keys(password).perform()
    sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='action-login' and contains(@class, 'ati-core-button')]").click()
    sleep(2)
    print("AUTHORIZATION ")


def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7')
    # options.add_extension("D:\\UB\\cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm.crx")
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    get_url(driver)
    authorization(driver)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `ActionChains`:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(login_btn).click().send_keys(login).perform()
```